# how to insert array of data into database

Tags: php, implode

here my code-

```
$things = mysql_real_escape_string(implode(',', $_POST['things']),$link);

$q = "INSERT INTO tblslider(src) VALUES ('".$things."')";
print_r($q);
$result = $mysqli->query($q) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
```

but my query is getting generated 
`INSERT INTO tblslider(src) VALUES ('4368122.jpg,5440051.jpg,1047428.jpg')`    but it should be
`INSERT INTO tblslider(src) VALUES ('4368122.jpg'),('5440051.jpg'),('1047428.jpg')` thats why it is taking it as one record not three.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do:

```
$things = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_POST['things']);
$q = "INSERT INTO tblslider(src) VALUES ('". implode("'),('", $things)."')";
```

It generates (with my test data):

```
INSERT INTO tblslider(src) VALUES ('a.jpg'),('b.jpg'),('c.jpg')
```

I forgot: Only use functions like `mysql_real_escape_string` on the *real* data, not the SQL string. In your example you apply the function on the already concatenated data.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$formatVals = function($x){$rx = mysql_real_escape_string($x); return "('$rx')";};

$valString = implode(',', array_map($formatVals, $_POST['things']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO tblslider (src) VALUES $valString";
```

Comment: You need PHP 5.3 for that, don't you?

Comment: no not for array_map, for the anonymous function maybe you'd need create_function instead of what i did, but it can still be done   http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php    http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php       http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: more importantly, i forgot the parens

Comment: Yeah I know that you don't need it for `array_map`. But your code will generate `"INSERT INTO tblslider (src) VALUES 'mysql_real_escape_string(a.jpg)','mysql_real_escape_string(b.jpg)','mysql_real_escape_string(c.jpg)'"` which is not correct. `mysql_real_escape_string()` has to be evaluated by PHP, not be contained in the string. It is not a MySQL function.

Comment: never thought it was mysql function, but i thoughy that it would parse just like "x = $x".  that statement is in double quotes, the singles are just there

Answer (score 0):

You have imploded things which is now an array, so you need to iterate over this with a foreach loop such as...

```
foreach ($things as $item) {

  $q = "INSERT INTO tblslider(src) VALUES ('".$item."')";
  echo '<br />'.$q;
  $result = $mysqli->query($q) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

}
```

You could echo $q to make sure you're getting the queries right for each item also.

Comment: Oops, my mistake. How about using str_replace
$things = str_replace (',' '),(', $things);